# Rails: undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Solved: the issue was from Lob's internal server error on their end.

I'm going through the following example taken from [this blog on Lob](https://lob.com/blog/print-mail-custom-postcards-using-html-css-ruby-on-rails/), and the code can be found [on Github here](https://github.com/lob/lob-rails-example)

After I cloned the repo, I `bundle installed` the gems, fired up the server, and head towards `localhost:3000/postcards`. After inputting a short message in the Message field, I am redirected to an error page with the *undefined method `first' for nil:NilClass* error.

The error appears to be in the controller

```
class PostcardsController < ApplicationController

  LOB = Lob.load(api_key: "test_0dc8d51e0acffcb1880e0f19c79b2f5b0cc")

  def index
  end

  def create
    template_file = ERB.new(File.open(File.join(Rails.root, 'app', 'views', 'postcards', 'postcard_front.html.erb')).read)
    custom_html = template_file.result(binding)

    @results = LOB.postcards.create(
      name: "Demo Postcard",
      to: {
        name: params[:postcards][:to_name],
        address_line1: params[:postcards][:to_address_line1],
        city: params[:postcards][:to_city],
        state: params[:postcards][:to_state],
        zip: params[:postcards][:to_zip],
        country: "US",
      },
      from: {
        name: params[:postcards][:from_name],
        address_line1: params[:postcards][:from_address_line1],
        city: params[:postcards][:from_city],
        state: params[:postcards][:from_state],
        zip: params[:postcards][:from_zip],
        country: "US",
      },
      front: custom_html,
      message: params[:postcards][:message],
      full_bleed: 1
    )
  end

end
```

From the tutorial blog, it appears that this error should not be happening. What is this error, and why is it happening on my environment?

Comment: Please take a look (or post in the question) the [stack trace](http://railscasts.com/episodes/24-the-stack-trace?view=asciicast) from the `development.log`. There you will find the exact location of the error.

Comment: Also, if you look that the blog page comment at the bottom, you are not the only one getting this error. It seems that this is a bug in the lob gem. The full stack trace might still help here.

Comment: @BoraMa After looking at the error messages / logs in more detail, it appears to be a 500 error on Lob's server. Thanks for introducing stack trace though, I learned something new today.

Answer (score 1):

There is an open issue on this at GitHUb. I am getting the same error. 7/27/2016